# "generally speaking" or "speaking generally"?

Tags: word-order

> I’m not convinced—and, **speaking generally**, no one should be
>   convinced—of anything not supported by hard data.

Wouldn't the phrase "**generally speaking**" sound more natural in the above sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one sense, “generally speaking” is more natural: it's much more common (according to [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=generally+speaking%2Cspeaking+generally&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) for *generally speaking,speaking generally*).  As such, it has a flatter and more cliched tone.   “Speaking generally” is perfectly acceptable English, perfectly natural, and should not be discriminated against.

I don't know of an adverb placement rule that applies here.  But you may find some of the following of interest: [Position of adverbs](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv202.shtml), bbc.co.uk;  [Should an adverb go before or after a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9702), ELU; [The Royal Order of Adverbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/79547), ELU; and especially [Does adverb come before the verb or after the verb?](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/147774-does-adverb-come-before-verb-after-verb.html), usingenglish.com.